# Using prefix option for flex in automake/flex/bison stack

Tags: makefile, bison, flex-lexer, automake

I'm converting a build process to use automake/libtool and I've hit a road block for supporting a .l/.y set.

The original build process did these two steps:

```
flex -t  -Pq_parser_yy ../../code/q_parser.l > q_parser.h
bison ../../code/q_parser.y -o q_parser.c
```

Flex:  I don't know how to recreate the -P option from the Makefile.am. In my Makefile.am I just list q_parser.l and let automake figure out what to do -- but it outputs q_parser.c not q_parser.h.

The q_parser.h is then included by q_parser.y which outputs q_parser.c. Very confusing for someone who has never used flex/bison!

So on to how it works from automake:

```
.l.c:
  $(am__skiplex) $(SHELL) $(YLWRAP) $< $(LEX_OUTPUT_ROOT).c $@ -- $(LEXCOMPILE)

q_parser.c: $(db_dir)/q_parser.l
  $(am__skiplex) \
  $(SHELL) $(YLWRAP) `test -f '$(db_dir)/q_parser.l' || echo '$(srcdir)/'`$(db_dir)/q_parser.l $(LEX_OUTPUT_ROOT).c q_parser.c -- $(LEX) $(LFLAGS) $(AM_LFLAGS)

.y.c:
  $(am__skipyacc) $(SHELL) $(YLWRAP) $< y.tab.c $@ y.tab.h $*.h y.output $*.output -- $(YACCCOMPILE)
```

So automake is mapping .l -> .c and .y -> .c so I run in to the error where gcc is trying to read the .l -> .c output and falling over itself.

I need to override automake to perform .l -> .h and then I should be ok to let it take the wheel. Any tips?

Comment: Nominally, the Flex part would be achieved by adding `-t -P q_parser_yy` to LFLAGS.  Alternatively, you could use the `--header-file=q_parser.h` option in place of the `-t` option.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the --header-file option. It looks like I will continue to fight automake in this matter, as the --header-file option is not support. The build process assumes the output of .c and not .h in the filename.
http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2011-06/msg00004.html

Comment: Removed libtool tag, as it didn't seem to have much to do with libtool.

Answer (score 2):

You could just bypass all that neat stuff since it's getting in your way:

```
q_parser.h : ../../code/q_parser.l
        $(LEX) $(LFLAGS) $(AM_LFLAGS) -Pq_parser_yy -o$@ $<
q_parser.c : ../../code/q_parser.y q_parser.h
        $(YACC) $(YFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

It doesn't seem that POSIX compatibility is what you're after now anyway.

Comment: Good point -- I can just override the targets. Would you consider this a build smell?

Comment: Why would it smell?  It's just doing what you're already doing, just using make to keep track of when things are rebuilt.